# using tor-win32/TOR as a proxy for newsgroup software

Tags: configuration, windows

I'm configuring a newsgroup software to connect to a news/NNTP server thru TOR (tor-win32) as a proxy.

where do I put tor-win32 info within newsgroup software and where do I put
news/NNTP server within TOR/tor-win32 arguement

thank's in advance :)

Comment: Does the software allow you to use a SOCKS5 proxy? If not, then it is not compatible.

Comment: thank's for replying. Yes id does use SOCKS5 proxy. So instead of passing SOCKS5 to the software
I pass TOR 127.0.0.1 $TOR_PORT.
remark that once tor-win32 is started via Windows shell it can't take input from the prompt
thank's